# Laravel Mix (Webpack) error when running on another machine

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I have a Laravel project and added Laravel Mix to it so I can develop with Vue.  It works fine on the machine I made it with but when I try to run it on another machine, I run `npm install` then `npm run watch` and get the following error:

> NODE_ENV=development webpack --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
>
> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:615
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/RuleSet'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:613:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:25)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:17)
>       at require

Comment: Are your two machines using the same version of webpack?

Comment: yep! same version

Comment: Have you tried removing node_modules (`rm -rf node_modules`) and re-installing all dependencies (`npm install`)?

Comment: Are they using the same, or at least not drastically different, versions of node and npm? `node --version && npm --version`